# Android : looking for equivalent of using switch with variable

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

In my app, I need to play sound on a button click (a dice rolling sound to be more specific) but i don't want to play the same sound as the previous one since throwing a dice never make the same sound.

So, I have 4 different sound and i want to pick, if possible, with the same probability, one of them which is not already playing

To do this, I want to use this :

```
MediaPlayer sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4;
Random rnd;

//Random and MediaPlayer are set up in the onCreate method

public void playSound() {
    int a, b, c, d, pos = 0, neg = 0;

    if (sound1.isPlaying()) {neg++; a = neg;} else {pos++; a = pos;}
    if (sound2.isPlaying()) {neg++; b = neg;} else {pos++; b = pos;}
    if (sound3.isPlaying()) {neg++; c = neg;} else {pos++; c = pos;}
    if (sound4.isPlaying()) {neg++; d = neg;} else {pos++; d = pos;}
    //available MediaPlayer associated to 1, 2, 3 ...
    //other MediaPlayer associated to -1, -2, -3 ...

    if (pos>0){
        switch (rnd.nextInt(pos) + 1) {
            case a: sound1.start(); break;
            case b: sound2.start(); break;
            case c: sound3.start(); break;
            case d: sound4.start(); break;
        }
    }
    //pick a MediaPlayer among those associated to a positive number
}
```

but Android does not allow to use variable with case, so I get an error saying "constant expression required"

The question is: how can I do the same by using things android allow to use?

As a beginner i didn't found any answer except using a "if" which is listing all possible case

(I'm not really interested by a giant "if", since I plan to add 2 or 3 other sound, the number of possibility will reach 2^6 or 2^7, meaning 64 or 128)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow your sounds to be placed in an array (a much better approach for when you want to add more of them) you can do all of this much more easily.

In pure Java (using 8 here):

```
MediaPlayer sounds[] = {sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4};
Random rnd;

public void playSound() {
    // Collect candidates - i.e. those that aren't playing right now.
    List<MediaPlayer> candidates = Arrays.stream(sounds)
            // Only not-playing ones.
            .filter(s -> !s.isPlaying())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Pick a random one.
    MediaPlayer picked = candidates.get(rnd.nextInt(candidates.size()));
    // Play your sound.

}
```

a Java-7 version of the gathering of the candidates

```
    // Collect candidates - i.e. those that aren't playing right now.
    List<MediaPlayer> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
        if ( !sounds[i].isPlaying() ) {
            candidates.add(sounds[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i added "if (candidates.size()>0) " before picking the media player to avoid error, thx you solved my problem